# Read a TAG Key's value within AWS EC2 instance

Tags: bash, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

I'm trying to read the **Name** tag of an ec2 instance and set it as the hostname automatically using user data. Currently I'm using

```
#!/bin/bash
apt update && apt-get install -y awscli
DOMAIN=domain.com
EC2_REGION=$(curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document|grep region|awk -F\" '{print $4}')
INSTANCE_ID=$(/usr/bin/curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
NAME_TAG=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --region=$EC2_REGION --instance-id=$INSTANCE_ID --output text | grep TAGS | grep Name | awk -F"\t" '{print $3}')
HOSTNAME=$(echo $NAME_TAG | awk '{print tolower($0)}' | sed -e 's/ /-/g' -e 's/[()]//g')
```

Code goes too cumbersome. Is there a better way to achieve the same
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Python to parse your JSON (I'm not sure whether you consider this less cumbersom or more cumbersome ... now that I've gone to the effort of typing it out it doesn't seem all *that* readable to me?!):

```
HOSTNAME=$(aws ec2 describe-instances --instance-id=$INSTANCE_ID | python -c"
import sys
import json
ec2_info = json.loads(''.join(sys.stdin.readlines()))
print [t['Value'] 
          for t in ec2_info['Reservations'][0]['Instances'][0]['Tags'] 
          if t['Key'] == 'Name'][0]
")
```

Comment: Thanks @maxymoo, using the above i think i can go with python alone in userdata leaving out bash, thanks much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a shell function that exports all of the identity doc into ones env:

```
get_identity_document() {
    curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document \
        | grep -v "[{}]" \
        | sed -e 's/\s*"\([^"]*\)"\s*:\s*"*\([^",]*\)"*,*/export \1=\2/' 
}
```

You just eval the output to get something like:

```
export devpayProductCodes=null
export privateIp=xx.xx.xx.xx
export availabilityZone=us-west-2a
export version=2010-08-31
export instanceId=i-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
export billingProducts=null
export instanceType=t2.large
export accountId=XXXXXXXXXX
export imageId=ami-63ac5803
export pendingTime=2016-04-08T17:55:53Z
export architecture=x86_64
export kernelId=null
export ramdiskId=null
export region=us-west-2
```

Then once you have that, you can use these others that extract other misc AWS instance data into your shell env

This is the generic one for instance data that the subsequent ones refine:

```
# Query instance data 
get_instance_data() { 
if [ "$3" ] ; then
       query=".$3"     
fi     
aws ec2 describe-instances --region=$2 --instance-id=$1 --query "Reservations[].Instances[]${query}" \
       --output text  
}
```

Get tag data:

```
# Get all tags for an instance prefixed by $3 or tag_
get_instance_tag_vars() {

   get_instance_data $1 $2 "Tags[]" \
       | tr '\t' '=' \
       | sed -e "s/^/export ${3:-tag_}/" 
}
```

Get volume Id

```
# Get instance volume ID from block device
# eg: get_instance_volume_id $instanceId  $region /dev/sda
get_instance_volume_id() {

   get_instance_data $1 $2 "BlockDeviceMappings[?starts_with(DeviceName, '$3')].Ebs.VolumeId" 
}
```

etc. You can append other JMESpath query strings to refine as needed.

ie:

```
eval $(get_identity_document)
eval $(get_instance_tag_vars $instanceId $region)
```

Now all your tags are in your shell's env prefixed by tag_

Comment: Thanks Bruce, great answer for all requirements.